# Status code 500 when deleting an object using axios and Symfony but deletion works

Tags: symfony, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

I'm using vue as my frontend. I want to delete an object from my database when a button is pressed, I post the selected object with axios but I get the following error:

```
wish.js:40 Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

even though my object does get deleted from my database.

Here is my code:

```
 postWishToBeDeleted({commit}, wishId) {
    console.log(wishId);
    axios.post('/api/post/delete', {
        wishId: wishId
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    }).then( response => {
        commit('removeWish', wishId);
        }
    )
}
```

Inside my symfony controller:

```
     /**
     * @Route("/api/post/delete", name="app_api_post_delete", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function deleteWish(Request $request, WishRepository $repository) {

        $data = $request->getContent();
        $data = json_decode($data, true);
        $wish = $repository->find($data['wishId']);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($wish);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->json($wish);
    }
```

I think that something with my response is wrong, I'm still new to Vue and axios so I'm not sure how return the json object correctly

EDIT:

I noticed that this error only occurs if I have more than one object?? If I it's only one and I delete it, there's no error

Comment: I don't use Symfony but `return $this->json($wish)` looks suspicious.  If `$wish` has been removed, maybe the problem is trying to send it as JSON.  What if you `return` something else like `return true`?

Comment: @Dan That might just be the problem! I tried returning this instead: return $this->json([
            'message' => 'Wish has been deleted'
        ]); and everything works fine, thanks :)

Comment: Nice, you're welcome.  I'll post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status 500 is a server error, and it sounds from the behavior that whatever causes the error must happen after the item is removed.

Looking at the `deleteWish` method, if `$wish` has been removed, maybe the problem is trying to convert it to JSON when it's undefined.  Try to return something else like:

```
return true;
```